# Proof that "every positive measurable function is a point limit of an increasing sequence of positive simple functions"?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, measurable-functions

We all know that

> Every positive measurable function is a point limit of an increasing sequence of positive simple functions

I would be very grateful if anyone could suggest a book well illustrates the proof of the previous theorem or a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Modern Theory of Integration - [Robert G.Bartle] - 2001
Theorem 19.15, p. 331